# LLVM opt doesn't work on macOS Big Sur: -bash: opt: command not found

Tags: macos, clang, llvm

I downloaded LLVM from the repository with `git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git` and installed it on macOS Big Sur using the following commands:

```
$ cmake ../llvm -G "Unix Makefiles" \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/llvm-project/build \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang
```

The installation went well and I can compile my *foo.c* program using `clang -c -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.bc` obtaining *foo.bc*.

However, when I use `opt -dot-cfg foo.bc` to obtain the CFG, I have this error: *-bash: opt: command not found*.

Has anyone had this error? The solutions for previous versions of O.S. did not work!

Comment: _"I can compile my foo.c program using clang"_ - Are you sure you are using your newly built clang and not the one shipped with XCode? `opt` should be inside `~/llvm-project/build/bin` alongside `clang`.

Comment: @mcilloni, thank you! Your comment solved the question! I was not using the `clang` that I installed manually! When I compiled putting the path to my `clang` and my `opt`, it worked perfectly!

ps.: If you want, you could post as an answer for me to accept it as a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I can compile my `foo.c` program using `clang`"* - Are you sure you are using your newly built `clang` and not the one shipped with XCode? `opt` should be inside `~/llvm-project/build/bin` alongside `clang`. **– Solved by @mcilloni in May 2 at 17:38**

Answer (score 0):

when you clone a git project, you do not need to include the file. You just need to type

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm
```

Comment: Hi, @Evergreen! If I don't include the file, I get an error as a response (*fatal: repository 'https://github.com/llvm/' not found*). So I included it all the way to the llvm-project.

Comment: Yep, My bad, i made a new answer that should work, for real this time

Answer (score 0):

You use two dots when calling the command.

```
../llvm
```

this tells bash "move up one directory level" and llvm is not one directory level up. this will work:

```
cmake ./llvm -G "Unix Makefiles" \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/llvm-project/build \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang
```

Comment: After I clone the repository, I run  `cd llvm-project` and `mkdir build && cd build`.

Then, I run the command inside the *build*. If I remove a dot from `../llvm`, an error occurs because I cannot find the directory in the path indicated by `./llvm`.

Comment: i dont know :( sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The tool `opt` is installed in `$HOME/llvm-project/build/bin`.

You need to add `$HOME/llvm-project/build/bin` in your $PATH

Comment: Tks, @philippe! That didn't work! I believe I'm using Clang
sent with XCode, as said by @mcilloni. I will look at this and try again!

Comment: Try `find $HOME/llvm-project -name opt` If you can not find it, that means it's not build properly. Did you run `cmake --build .; make install` after `cmake ../llvm ...` ?

Comment: Yes! I do! The comment from @mcilloni resolved the issue! Tks for your help!